# Can't make changes to excel drawing in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

Any clue how to copy an excel drawing into Visio and be able to make changes? So far I don't like this program.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy an Excel drawing and paste into another program (like Visio) it gets copied as just a picture. Instead of copy/paste try **Insert -> Object**.